# When resetting the ContentPane, button function no longer works properly Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, contentpane

I have the following actionevent on a button which takes me from the home screen to the second screen.

```
public void advancedBtnAction(ActionEvent evt, JFrame frame) {                                         

    frame.remove(this.getContentPane());
    frame.setContentPane(new advancedHome(frame).getContentPane());
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.pack();

}
```

When I am on this screen I have the option to go back, this is the code for this button. This brings everything back that was on the home screen fine however when I click on the above button again it doesnt do anything?

```
public void BackButton(ActionEvent evt, JFrame frame) {                                         

    frame.remove(this.getContentPane());
    frame.setContentPane(new printerHome(this).getContentPane());
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.pack();
}
```

Could anyone help me with getting advancedBtnAction to work again after being bought back onto the content pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this type of requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know how I get on